# Saving Profile information in a Facebook App

Tags: facebook, fbml

I am making a facebook app in FBML. I want to know what all information can I store about the user permanently into my database? Also, can I have access to the user's email address of the user after logging into my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read section III of the [Developer Principles & Policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/#data)